# Read float from a line throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a .txt file in the format of an integer followed by a float and they are separated by the space character in every line. I want to read the float from every line and then put it in an array.
Here is my code so far, but when I run it it gives me a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

because I guess it never creates the second value:

```
BufferedReader reader = null;
            try{
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(
                        new File(root.getAbsolutePath().toString()+"/samplefile.txt"))));
                String line = null;
                String[] numbers = null;
                int i = 0;
                value.clear();
                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    numbers = line.split("/\\s/");
                    value.add(Float.valueOf(numbers[1].trim()));
                }
                mTextview5.setText(String.valueOf(value.get(1)));
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

So how can I go to second value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
numbers = line.split("\\s+");
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using a debugger? 
You would get a result pretty fast, where the program stops and crashes.

A arraylist (your value) should not throw a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.
My guess would be your possible faulty regex.

```
numbers = line.split("/\\s/");
numbers[1] # there is a possibility that your "split regex" 
#returns a smaller array than expected, thus ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.
```

Try a regextester like http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this? `numbers = line.split(" ");`
the problem is your regexp. And with a debugger it's better for you to understand your code's problem.